# How to use excel files with Nest JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, typescript, nestjs

I am trying to creat a rest api which uses a third part api to get some status. I'll get the url from a excel file, for this specific case it needs to be a excel file, use them in my service to obtain the data from the third part api and save this response in the same excel file. I am already able to get the data from the third part api, but I'm failing to manage the excel through nest js. I tried to use exceljs library but it didn't work as I intended. I would like to have the return(assume it is inside a function) to be the cell value in this excel file. Could someone give me some hint in how to handle this file use inside nest js?

```
let Excel = require('exceljs');
    let workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workBook.xlsx.readFile('./ExcelFile/Archive.xlsx').then(function()
    {
        let sheet = workBook.getWorkSheet("Sheet1");
        let cellValue = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).value;
    });
    return cellValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since cellValue is defined inside a callback (`.then(() => {}`) you will need to return inside the callback.

Here however you you will face the issue that you cannot return it inside the callback.
To fix this you have 2 options: Use async/await or return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Async/await:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');

async function ReadCell(filename) {
    let workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
    await workBook.xlsx.readFile(filename);

    let sheet = workBook.getWorkSheet('Sheet1');
    let cellValue = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).value;
    
    return cellValue;
}
```

Promises:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');

async function ReadCell(filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let workBook = new Excel.Workbook();
        workBook.xlsx.readFile(filename).then(() => {
            let sheet = workBook.getWorkSheet('Sheet1');
            let cellValue = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).value;
            resolve(cellValue);
        }).catch(err => /* Do some error handling here if you want to */ reject(err));
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that when using promises you are going to need to use `.then((result) => {/* your code here */})` when trying to get the result of your ReadCell() function.

You can find more info about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it didn't work in my nest js service. I've read the library exceljs documentation and it should have been working.
My last attempt was that one, it says it can't find the file:
async readExcel()
    {
        
        const workbook = new Workbook();
        const fileName = "./Archive.xlsx";
        await workbook.xlsx.readFile(fileName);
        const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');
        const rawDataCell = worksheet.getRow(2).getCell(1).value;
        const cell = JSON.stringify(rawDataCell);        return cell;  
    }

Comment: You can use the following code to view what directory it's trying to read from and make sure it's correct: ```console.log(require('path').resolve(filename))```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to read the file, but now I'm facing a problem with the type of answer I'm getting. The value of the cell is a string, but the return is being interpreted as a cell type so it fails to fullfil the requirements of the function I use. I tried to use JSON.stringfy(obj) but it put extra "" in the string so it got unusable. Do u have any suggestion how to convert the variable type?

Comment: Should just be .value to get the cell contents

Comment: Thank u very much for the support, I managed to achieve what I needed to do in my code